# Select 2 - Unable to select previously selected options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have few select fields generated in the HTML using a loop as below:

```
<isloop items="${pdict.phoneData}" var="phone" status="loopState">
   <select 
   required 
   class="form-control phoneType ps-select"
   id="phoneType${loopState.index}">
   <option id="" value="">Select</option>
   <isloop items="${phoneTypeMapping}" var="type">
      <option id="${type.label}"
      ${type.value === phone.PhoneTypeID ? 'selected' : ''} 
      value="${type.value}">${type.label}
      </option>
   </isloop>
   </select>
</isloop>
```

As you can see above, my select element is inside a loop and my options are also looped.

I am initializing the Select2 plugin on page load as below:

```
function initializeSelect2(selectElementObj) {
    selectElementObj.select2({
        width: "100%",
        tags: true,
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownParent: selectElementObj.closest('.ps-floating-form-field')
    });
}

// Initialize select2 plugin
$('.ps-select').each(function () {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) {
        initializeSelect2($(this));
    }
});
```

After my page loads, I am seeing that I am unable to select the options that are selected in other select elements. The options appear greyed-out.

[image]

As in the above image, you can see that both 'mobile' and 'home' options are disabled. Mobile option is selected in the previous dropdown only, not the current one.

I want to be able to select all options in all select dropdowns, irrespective of their selections in previous elements.

Comment: Why do you use tag?

Comment: Finally, was able to zero-in on the cause of the issue. It was due to the id that was used for options inside the loop. So, essentially, the option's id should also be unique.

Comment: `ids` must always be unique.

Comment: Why does an `<option>` need an `id=` at all?  If it's not a *DOM* id but instead it's a data "id" such as `${type.label}` then use `data-id='${type.label}'` - though "label" seems questionable as an "id" as it will likely have spaces/other non-label-esq characters

Comment: @Prashanth you should an a (detailed) *answer* explaining what the problem was an how you fixed it.  Or close your question.

Comment: @freedomn-m: I have given an answer in my first comment, as you can see, that the issue was with using 'id' for options, which was not necessary. Removing the id from option tag totally worked.

Comment: Start a new comment, don't type, read the "placeholder" text:  *Avoid answering questions in comments."  - if you add an **answer** (not a comment) then the question will have an answer and it will help people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, was able to zero-in on the cause of the issue. It was due to the id that was used for options inside the loop. So, essentially, the option's id should also be unique or you do not need an id for options.